# Do I need to modify the dts?

Tags: embedded-linux, i2c

Attached a new device (maxim 3107 i2c-to-uart) to i2c2.  Unable to talk to it via /dev/i2c-1.  Do I need to add this to the device tree blob?  Kernel version 4.9.89

```
# i2cdetect -y -r -1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

```
  const char *i2cDevice1 = "/dev/i2c-1";
  int i2cAddr = 0x59; 

  int fdI2c1 = open(i2cDevice1, O_RDWR);
  if (fdI2c1 < 0) {
    printf("I2C Error 1.  Bye.\n");
    return 0;
  }     /* this WORKS */

  if (ioctl(fdI2c1, I2C_SLAVE, i2cAddr) < 0) {
    printf("I2C Error 2. Bye.\n");
    return 0;
  }    /* this WORKS */

  char buf[10];
  buf[0] = DIVLSB;
  buf[1] = Div1;
  if (write(fdI2c1, buf, 2) != 2) {
    printf("I2C Error 3. Bye.\n");
    return 0;
  }    /* this FAILS */
```

If I need to modify the blob, is this maxim block the correct thing to add to the .dts?

```
&i2c2 {
        clock-frequency = <400000>;
        max3107@58 {
                compatible = “maxim, 3107”;
                reg = <0x58>;
        };
};
```

Comment: From where you have got `0x59` in the code or `0x58` in DTS? Address from the detection is `0x48`.

Comment: Hi Oandriy.  The detection was another device.  My post inadvertently mixed two variants of the dts tweak and the user code trying to write to the device.  Currently using 0x2c in both spots.  Thanks for pointing that out.  Nevertheless, I am neither detecting nor able to write the device.  Still puzzled.  Steve

Comment: So, the detection works or not? Can you update post with actual information? (Btw, users can be notified when you use `@user` form in the comment)

Comment: No, detection of the device at 0x2c does not work.  And the max3107 device did not show up in my device tree blob.  Code correction:  replace 0x59 and 0x58 with 0x2c.  @user

Comment: @0andriy   Does this cause you to be notified?

Comment: Yes, it does. And the question here, where did you get this address from? 0x2c (if it's 7-bit representation) should be 0x58 in Linux. But in any case, if `i2cdetect` doesn't find it, so how does driver?

Comment: By the way, compatible string you have is wrong. https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/58afc909772c9bffef24f20618693f64e7cfe96f shows it has to be `maxim,max3107`.

Comment: And one more notice, you are talking about bus name `i2c-2`, while in the detection command line you supply `1`. Is it intentional?

Comment: Thanks.  I will correct the compatible string.  The 7 bit vs 8 bit ambiguity and vendor inconsistency is a hassle but resolvable via trial and error.  the i2cdetect utility doesn't also work as desired but I put the results in the posting.  @0andriy